# Tron transactionBuilder error Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, solidity, tron, tronweb

I am getting this type of error **Cannot read property 'address' of undefined** while i am calling sendTRX function

````
{
   const privateKey = "***"; 
var fromAddress = window.tronWeb.address.toHex("TR18f2revPbnb9dzFTqYQ5TKaBjX1QEtsC"); //address _from
var toAddress = window.tronWeb.address.toHex("TC4AKrNsrhG3h1pnY7SjjNcqQpDNhmNTuY"); //address _to
var amount = 10000000; //amount
//Creates an unsigned TRX transfer transaction
console.log(fromAddress);
//console.log(window.tronWeb.address.toHex(fromAddress));

const tradeobj = await window.tronWeb.transactionBuilder.sendTrx(
      fromAddress,
      amount,
      toAddress
);
const signedtxn = await window.tronWeb.trx.sign(
      tradeobj,
      privateKey
);
const receipt = await window.tronWeb.trx.sendRawTransaction(
      signedtxn
);
console.log('- Output:', receipt, '\n');
}
sendTRX();```
````

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue I resolved it by putting the file into htdocs (XAMPP) folder and accessing it by HTTP://localhost/trontest.html ,So I think **window.tronWeb** is only accessible in HTTP or HTTPS
So you can use XAMPP or Node or any server.

Here is my code for trontest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick="gettronweb()">Can you get tronweb from tronlink?</button>
    <script>
        function gettronweb(){
            if(window.tronWeb && window.tronWeb.defaultAddress.base58){
                document.write("Yes, catch it:",window.tronWeb.defaultAddress.base58)
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is tronlink chrome extension related.
When you call window object , make sure you are logged in on your tronlink wallet.

Without tronlink make sure to define user ports with function:

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (!window.tronWeb) {
    const HttpProvider = TronWeb.providers.HttpProvider;
    const fullNode = new HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
    const solidityNode = new HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
    const eventServer = 'https://api.trongrid.io/';
    
    const tronWeb = new TronWeb(
        fullNode,
        solidityNode,
        eventServer,
    );
    window.tronWeb = tronWeb;
  }
};
```